# Why the following files isn't produced when I run MiKTeX in my laptop?

Tags: miktex, auxiliary-files

### **Background**

I am trying to configure MiKTeX in my new laptop. For this purpose I have installed the MiKTeX in the laptop and then trying to run the documents that were in my old computer in this new laptop. However, when I am running a particular document I am getting only the following files `.synctex.gz`, `.pdf` and a notepad file named `text document` whereas in my old computer for the same document I get not only the just-mentioned files, but also `.aux`, `.out`,`.rpi` files.

*In my laptop the only two softwares that was not there by default and had to be downloaded from the internet was Adobe Reader and MiKTeX.*

### **Question**

- How do I solve this problem?

I think that I am missing some other software(s) that I need to download but I am not sure. If that's the case then my question in addition to the above one is,

- What software(s) do I need to install?

**Addition (Possibly Important) Information**

- The operating system of my old computer is Windows 7 (32 bit).
- The operating system of my new laptop is Windows 10 (64 bit).

**The MWE of the Document of which I was Talking Above**

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,tikz,hyperref}
  \usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{a4paper}

  \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

  \title{The Title}
   \author{}
  \date{}
  \begin{document}
  \maketitle
\section{First Section}
Some Text.
\section{Second Section}
Again Some Text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the windows settings so that it shows you all file extensions and also hidden folders. Check if your editor moves some files to another folder. Check in the log if pdflatex inputs an aux-file and from where.

Comment: Under what name are you saving the LaTeX file?

Comment: @egreg: `The Title. tex`.

Comment: Well, spaces in file names are not the best strategy with TeX. Particularly `. tex` is suspicious.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry I meant `The Title.tex`.

Comment: @user170039 remove also the other space

Comment: @egreg: The error is still the same.